# Best way to prevent two "bots" from working on the same database row?

Tags: mysql, database, automation

I have a few servers. Each server has a bot program. Bots are all connected to the same mysql database. What they do is, connect to the DB, query the DB and grab a .csv file containing `username;password` rows, log on the accounts on a specific website, do some automated stuff, set the finished accounts as `Done` on the database.

I'm having a hard time deciding the best way to ensure that all bots are able to pull data from the same DB poll, without conflicts and without leaving any account behind.

My ideas were:

- Pre-define what row ranges each bot will work.

For example:

```
Bot1 = row 0 to row 999
Bot2 = row 1000 to row 1999
Bot3 = row 2000 to row 2999 ...
```

This can be a problem because if I need to scale, I will have to go pre-defining every bot.

- Make a column called `bot` => Make each bot select 500 rows, add a predefined value to the 
  column `bot` on all the 500 rows => Only work on the rows `WHERE bot = 'pre-defined value'`

This would work but there may still have some collision. Besides that, my bots need to work on CSV files, so they can't actually work on the fly on the databases.

My concern is scalability. I want to be able to add as many servers as I want and have them all working nicelly with each other.

Suggestions?

I was reading about mysql lock() function, but I don't think it would work in this case due to the way my bots get the acconts (.csv files).

Comment: Use a modulo for the bot to figure out which rows to grab: row_id % bot_id.  While you're not hardcoding the bot ranges, you are hardcoding the number of bots.  You can also update the batches inside of a transaction, where only one can get the "next 1000" at a time.

Comment: So it would be like the second option I stated above?

Comment: It's not great from an indexing point of view, but I was thinking something like this (if you had 10 bots):  SELECT * from passwordTable where alreadyProcessed = 0 and id % 10 = 0

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.

What I did was:

I made a PHP API that gets a random row that has status = 0 and prints its information in XML format. Then I use GET requests in my bot to get a random row using this PHP script and put it on a variable. Later, I use regex to scrape each column from the earlier variable and put them on their respective variables. After my bot finishes running on that account, it sets status = 1 on the row it just grabbed using my PHP API, so other bots won't touch this row again. This way I can have several servers running with no problem of colissions, no problems with .CSVs and the only problem is that now I have more load on my mysql server but that won't be too hard to solve.